# Can I create a annotated Faces Application Listener Class?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I want to create a Faces application Listener with annotation 
I have the following class:

```
package com.chhibi.listener;

    import javax.faces.application.Application;
    import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;
    import javax.faces.event.PostConstructApplicationEvent;
    import javax.faces.event.PreDestroyApplicationEvent;
    import javax.faces.event.SystemEvent;
    import javax.faces.event.SystemEventListener;

    public class FacesAppListener implements SystemEventListener {

        @Override
        public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {

            if (event instanceof PostConstructApplicationEvent) {
                // other code here
            }

            if (event instanceof PreDestroyApplicationEvent) {
                //other code here
            }

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
            // only for Application
            return (source instanceof Application);

        }
    }
```

and I want to replace the configuration of `faces-config.xml` following by an annotation, what to do?

```
<!-- Application is started -->
        <system-event-listener>
            <system-event-listener-class>
                com.chhibi.listenner.FacesAppListener
            </system-event-listener-class>
            <system-event-class>
                javax.faces.event.PostConstructApplicationEvent
            </system-event-class>                       
        </system-event-listener>     

        <!-- Before Application is shut down -->
        <system-event-listener>
            <system-event-listener-class>
                com.chhibi.listenner.FacesAppListener
            </system-event-listener-class>
            <system-event-class>
                javax.faces.event.PreDestroyApplicationEvent
            </system-event-class>                       
        </system-event-listener>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no annotation for that. Even more, you're essentially using the wrong tool for the purpose. Just use an [eagerly initialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html#eager%28%29) [application scoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ApplicationScoped.html) [managed bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) instead.

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyApplicationBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void onPostConstruct() {
        // Put code here which should be executed on application's startup.
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void onPreDestroy() {
        // Put code here which should be executed on application's shutdown.
    }

}
```

That's all. No additional XML verbosity necessary.

Alternatively, if you're not interested in the JSF artifacts as available by `FacesContext`, then you could also use the standard servlet context listener instead:

```
@WebListener
public class MyApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Put code here which should be executed on application's startup.
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Put code here which should be executed on application's shutdown.
    }

}
```

Also here, no additional XML necessary.

The `SystemEventListener` is intented to be attached to an `UIComponent` or a `Renderer` and not to be used standalone.